# SWT - computingSize for Multi-line textfield inside ScrolledComposite

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, scrolledcomposite

I have a composite(innerComposite) within a ScrolledComposite(sc). At runtime, additional UI components can be added. So I'm using the code below to set the minimum size of the sc to enable scrolling, in case that the additional UI components "overflow" the sc.

```
sc.setMinSize(
    innerComposite.computeSize(
        innerComposite.getSize().x, SWT.DEFAULT
    )
);
```

One issue is with the SWT Multi-Line textfield inside this sc/innerComposite.

```
textBox = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

When I enter a long text into this multi-line textfield, the vertical scrollbar will appear, (which is what I wanted!). However, when I call the code above to recompute the size and setting the sc.setMinSize()...the multi-line textfield's height will expand to fit the length of the text entered. This is not what I wanted. I want this height to remain on with the scrollbar and not resize to fit the text entered.

I know `computeSize` will cast its children to resize to the *preferred size*. I don't want this to happen to the multiline textfield as it has the capability of scrolling the vertical bar.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Researched a bit and I have to say this looks hopeless. You can't override the `computeSize` method of the `Text`, since subclassing is not allowed. The `computeSize` method of the `Layout` invokes `layout` which is a **huge** method. The only possibility I see is overriding this `layout` method (which iterates over it's children) and ignore any `Text` with style `SWT.MULTI`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of solving your problem is writing your own custom layout and setting that to your inner composite. This way you can control exactly how the controls will appear.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `GridLayout` in the content `Composite`. This allows you to set a `GridData` as `layoutData` on the text which contains both a `wHint`+`hHint` (which is used when doing `computeSize()` on the composite ) but still activate `verticalGrab` which will attribute any additional space to this composite.

In other words: the preferred size of the `GridLayout`ed `Composite` uses the `hHint`/`wHint` from the `GridData`'s of its children. This allows you to set the preferred size of you `Text` while still expanding the text using `GridData.verticalGrab` if extra space is available.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by setting the width/height!

Comment: How did you calculate the required dimensions?