# Compute the minimum size of a Composite

Tags: java, swt

I need to calculate the minimum or default size of a `Composite` where it can display all components without clipping.

I only seem to find methods to calculate the **preferred size** of the `Composite`. This means that a `Table` or other scrolled composite will have a preferred size which displays the full contents without scrolling. The `ScrolledComposite` will immediately go into scroll mode, which is not what I want.

`GridLayout` manages to do this by treating the `GridData` hints as minimum width/height, allowing grabbing any extra space available.

The problem is related to this one: [SWT - computingSize for Multi-line textfield inside ScrolledComposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834482/swt-computingsize-for-multi-line-textfield-inside-scrolledcomposite)

Answer (score 3):

[`Control#computeSize(int, int)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#computeSize(int,%20int)) should be what you are searching for:

```
Point size = comp.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
System.out.println(size.x + " " + size.y);
```

Comment: Control#computeSize will give you the size needed to show the text without a scrollbar. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find the solution.

The key was two different things:

1. Make sure to set the resize listener on both the content (if CHILDREN are added and layout() is called) and the `ScrolledComposite` (if it is resized from outside its children)
2. Make sure to set both `GridData.grab` and `GridData.hint`. The hint will make sure the composite assumes this size when you do `computeSize()`, while grab makes sure it will grab any extra space that is available.

Code sample is below:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
  Display display = new Display ();
  Shell shell = new Shell(display);
  ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.NONE);
  Composite foo = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
  foo.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
  StyledText text = new StyledText(foo, SWT.NONE);
  text.setText("Ipsum dolor etc... \n etc... \n etc....");
  GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).hint(40, 40).applyTo(text);

  Listener l = new Listener() {
     public void handleEvent(Event e) {
         Point size = sc.getSize();
         Point cUnrestrainedSize = content.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
         if(size.y >= cUnrestrainedSize.y && size.x >= cUnrestrainedSize.x) {
           content.setSize(size);
           return;
         }
         // does not fit
         Rectangle hostRect = getBounds();
         int border = getBorderWidth();
         hostRect.width -= 2*border;
         hostRect.width -= getVerticalBar().getSize().x;
         hostRect.height -= 2*border;
         hostRect.height -= getHorizontalBar().getSize().y;
         c.setSize(
           Math.max(cUnrestrainedSize.x, hostRect.width),
           Math.max(cUnrestrainedSize.y, hostRect.height)
         );
     }
  }
  sc.addListener(SWT.Resize, l);
  foo.addListener(SWT.Resize, l);

  shell.open ();
  while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
  }
  display.dispose ();
}
```